# 64-bit app calling 32-bit Windows service - VS 2013 debug

Tags: visual-studio-debugging

64-bit C# app calls into a 32-bit C# Windows service.  We can step through the 32-bit code after attaching to the service, but we cannot see the value of any variables.  We need the 32-bit service to access legacy 32-bit dlls.

Answer (score 0):

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2013/10/16/switching-to-managed-compatibility-mode-in-visual-studio-2013/

Explains the fix nicely, though this variant of the cause is not mentioned.  Considering how often this trips folks up, I think this might be called a Microsoft design flaw.

Comment: The option "Managed Compatibility Mode" was used to managed and mixed debugging but not to native-only debugging, it would be related to the process you want to attach. Anyway, since you have resolved this issue, you could mark it as the answer, so it would be helpful for other community members who meet the same issue, thanks for your sharing.

Comment: Jack Zhai-MSFT - sorry, I can't up vote my answer to my own question (but you could)